# Jasper Reports: How can I print multiple pages in one page

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am new to Jasper Reports. I have a report with 2 groups. Depending on the query, multiple pages are being printed.

1st Group Height -- 95 Points and 2nd Group Height -- 144 Points

I want these multiple pages to be printed in one page (I want to incorporate 5 pages in a page). Each page height is 239 Points. (Even if content of page is less than 239 Points, I want to keep the remaining part as blank and start the next page after 239 Points). I tried creating a Report and included the above report as a sub-report and set the height of main report as 1195 (239 * 5) Points. Still, these are being printed in different pages.

The result of export is:
[image: Report looks like this when it is printed]

The main report design is:
[image: Main Report - This is including 2 subreports]

The first subreport design is:
[image: First SubReport]

The second subreport design is:
[image: Second SubReport]

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your report's design in iReport?

Comment: @Alex, It was not allowing me to add images. Please find the link for report design _http://www.flickr.com/photos/78994541@N06

Answer (score 0):

I've made a test based on your specifications and it seems to work just fine. I can give you a couple of pointers here.

1. In your main-report design, the height of the sub-report element doesn't matter as long as it is equal to the underlying band. If the sub-report element is shorter, the difference will appear in the result.
2. The page height of the sub-report doesn't matter, just the total height of the bands.
3. Check to make sure that the "Start on a new Page" option hasn't been selected on the groups that you have created. This is the most likely issue.

If the top 3 hasn't fixed your problem, look through the sample below and compare differences.

**MainReport:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="MainReport1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="1195" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\Bizz\\Documents\\JasperReports\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     PRODUCT."ID" AS PRODUCT_ID,
     PRODUCT."NAME" AS PRODUCT_NAME,
     PRODUCT."COST" AS PRODUCT_COST
FROM
     "PUBLIC"."PRODUCT" PRODUCT]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="PRODUCT_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="PRODUCT_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PRODUCT_COST" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCT_ID}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="50"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="ProductID">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCT_ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "MainReport1_subreport2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Group2">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA["2"]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="50"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="ProductID">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCT_ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "MainReport1_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Subreport1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="MainReport1_subreport1" language="groovy" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="95" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="ProductID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     PRODUCT."ID" AS PRODUCT_ID,
     PRODUCT."NAME" AS PRODUCT_NAME,
     PRODUCT."COST" AS PRODUCT_COST
FROM
     "PUBLIC"."PRODUCT" PRODUCT
where
  product_id = $P{ProductID}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="PRODUCT_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="PRODUCT_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PRODUCT_COST" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="95" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[PRODUCT_ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCT_ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[PRODUCT_NAME]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="20" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCT_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[PRODUCT_COST]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="40" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCT_COST}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="200" height="35"/>
                <jr:barbecue xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" type="3of9" drawText="false" checksumRequired="false">
                    <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCT_ID}]]></jr:codeExpression>
                </jr:barbecue>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Subreport2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="MainReport1_subreport2" language="groovy" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="888" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="ProductID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     PRODUCT."ID" AS PRODUCT_ID,
     PRODUCT."NAME" AS PRODUCT_NAME,
     PRODUCT."COST" AS PRODUCT_COST
FROM
     "PUBLIC"."PRODUCT" PRODUCT
where
  product_id = $P{ProductID}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="PRODUCT_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="PRODUCT_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PRODUCT_COST" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="144" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[PRODUCT_ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCT_ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[PRODUCT_NAME]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="20" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCT_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[PRODUCT_COST]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="40" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCT_COST}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="302" height="84"/>
                <jr:barbecue xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" type="3of9" drawText="false" checksumRequired="false">
                    <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCT_ID}]]></jr:codeExpression>
                </jr:barbecue>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```